# CSS animation not playing right - choppy?

Tags: html, css

The rectangles are supposed to move down, the left then the right. But for some reason they just kind of "jump." Can someone please tell me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   <style>
     .imgbox
{
position: relative;
float:left;
text-align:center;
width:120px;
height:130px;
border:1px solid gray;
margin:0px;
margin-bottom:8px;
padding:0px;
-webkit-animation-name:drop;
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;

animation-name:drop;
animation-duration:2s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-play-state:running;
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes drop
{
0%  {top:10px;}
100% {top:100px;}
} 
 @keyframes drop
{
0%  {top:10px;}
100% {top:100px;}
}


    </style>

<div class="imgbox" id="stuff1" style="-webkit-animation-delay:1s; animation-delay:1s"></div>
<div class="imgbox" id="stuff2" style="-webkit-animation-delay:2s; animation-delay:2s"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically I just want one rectangle to undergo the animation and the next to do it as well, just slightly delayed. This is just an example, there is going to be many rectangles hence why I didn't just make separate divs.

Comment: Not tested but as I look at your code, seems like you need to set `top: 10px;` to `.imgbox` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's how things work in HTML - everything is in pixels, so when you're moving something, you can only move by X-number of pixels, or not move it.

You're moving your rectangles for 90 pixels for the duration of 2 seconds and there's just no way to make it smoother than it is.

However, if you're worried about that initial jump, it's because your element has a `top` value of zero, and when the animation starts it gets increased to 10 pixels right away, and then the animation continues. To avoid it, simply set their `top` property to `10px`.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/adePY/

Comment: Ok you added the however part later... before that didn't made sense to me :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Ah, sorry, thought you saw the whole thing. I wasn't sure which of the two issues OP needs fixing, so explained both. :)